# Get a "chain of events" in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CustomerID | ContactTime     | AttemptResult 
-----------+-----------------+-----------------
1          | 1/1/2016 5:00   | Record Started
1          | 1/1/2016 6:00   | Appointment 
2          | 1/2/2016 5:00   | Record Started
1          | 1/3/2016 6:00   | Sold
2          | 1/2/2016 5:00   | Sold
3          | 1/4/2016 5:00   | Record Started
3          | 1/4/2016 6:00   | Sold
```

From

```
 create table #temp1
(
    CustomerID int,
    ContactTime datetime,
    Result nvarchar(50)
)

insert into #temp1 values (1, '1/1/2016 5:00', 'Record Started')
insert into #temp1 values (1, '1/1/2016 6:00', 'Appointment')
insert into #temp1 values (2, '1/2/2016 5:00', 'Record Started')
insert into #temp1 values (1, '1/3/2016 6:00', 'Sold')
insert into #temp1 values (2, '1/2/2016 5:00', 'Sold')
insert into #temp1 values (3, '1/4/2016 5:00', 'Record Started')
insert into #temp1 values (3, '1/4/2016 6:00 ', 'Sold')
```

How can I query this in a way that gets all combinations in order of AttemptResults ? So something like:

```
CustID | Sequence
-------+--------------------------------------
1      | Record Started -> Appointment -> Sold 
2      | Record Started ->  Sold 
3      | Record Started ->  Sold
```

I'm not even sure where to start...

Answer (score -1):

If this is your complete dataset, I can help you. Otherwise I would need to see more. Use something called a *Window Function*. Below esentially indexes or keeps track of how many entries there are for each CustomerID.

```
    Select *, row_number() over (partition CustomerID group by ContactTime) as Combo
    into #temp
    from table
```

Then count how many combos of 2 happen (Record Started->Sold), combos of 3 (Record Started -> Appointment -> Sold )

```
   Select CustomerID, max(Combo) as MaxCombo
   into #temp1
   from #temp
   group by CustomerId

   Select MaxCombo, count(*)
   from #temp1
   group by MaxCombo
```

You could also use *Common Table Expressions* instead of these temp tables but I didnt want to add too much confusion.

Comment: This gives me `Incorrect syntax near 'CustomerID'.`

Comment: I changed it to `partition by CustomerID order by ContactTime` and fixed the error, but the results aren't what I'm looking for.